# How to play Apple Music files (even "available offline" ones) with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

Is it possible to play Apple Music files—even the "available offline" ones—with AVPlayer? I've tried the following code to retrieve the URL, but it returns nil:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection{
    [mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSURL *thisURL=[[[mediaItemCollection items] firstObject] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
...
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
[Discussions](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3720) on the Apple Developer forum suggest this may not be possible, unless AVPlayer is *not* used. But then that prevents audio processing, so not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Music assets are DRM protected, as expected. Additionally, offline songs do not have a valid Asset URL you can use with AVPlayer. The only way to play Apple Music songs is by using MusicKit with MPMusicPlayerController, or Apple Music API available in iOS 11.